# Adding data labels (annotations?) to Google Charts (Visualizations API) drawn from a query

Tags: google-sheets, charts, annotations, google-visualization, label

I'm creating a line chart by querying data entered into a Google Sheet, and I need to add data labels, i.e. the little numbers next to the points on the chart. I found plenty of documentation on how to do this with charts drawn from a manually entered data-table, but not from a query to a Google Sheet. Please help.

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']}); 
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
  'URL'
);
query.setQuery('SELECT A, B OFFSET 0'); //select specific cells from the table
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
}

var data = response.getDataTable();
var options = {
  title: '',
  height : 250,
  width : '100%',

    }
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: will you please share the code that creates the data table for the chart?

Comment: edited question to include code

Answer (score 0):

correct, you want to add *annotations*.

this can be done using an [annotation column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole).

the annotation column role, should directly follow the series column it represents in the data table.

in this case, since you are getting the data from a query,
we can use a `DataView` to add the annotation using a calculated column.

first, we create the data view.

```
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
```

then we use the `setColumns` method,
to add the column indexes from the query,
and our calculated column for the annotation.

```
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);
```

finally, we need to use the view to draw the chart.

```
chart.draw(view, options);
```

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'URL'
  );
  query.setQuery('SELECT A, B OFFSET 0'); //select specific cells from the table
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var options = {
    title: '',
    height : 250,
    width : '100%',
  };

  // create data view with calculated annotation column
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);  // <-- use view to draw the chart
}
```

---

Note: when using `google.visualization.LineChart`, you only need the `'corechart'` package.

the `'line'` package is for their *material* line chart --> `google.charts.Line`